# Do forced movements stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

When a combination of powers/feats each allow a push or slide of 1 square, can they be combined into a single forced move of 2

Specifically ...

`Artificer Power (1): Thundering Armor - "Hit: 1d8+3 thunder damage and you push the secondary target 1 square away from the primary target.`

combined with...

`Dragonmark Feat: Mark of Storm - "Whenever you hit an enemy with a thunder or lightning power, you can slide that enemy 1 square.`

Ok, in this case I'm thinking it'd be a push 1 from the attack, followed by a slide 1 from the feat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact same (in fact more detailed) question came up on the WotC boards. Here is the answer to your question:

> Hitting with *Thundering Armor* while having the Feat *Mark of Storm* result in a Push 1 and a Slide 1 because *Mark of Storm* doesn't increase any Forced Movement, it produces one on its own.

Where someone else explains how this sort of rule is adjudicated in D&D 4E:

> There isn't a rule which states you can't have more then one forced movement type. So the specific rule present in *MoS* that you get a slide has nothing to contradict it. 4e is Specific vs General, but it is also Rules Text vs Nothing At All.

**So yes, they 'stack'.**

---

Interestingly the OP on the WotC post also adds in the use of the *Quickbeam Staff*:

> Increases forced movement by 1.

This is a property of the `Forceful` enchantment.

> Forceful: Whenever you pull, push, or slide a target **with an attack power** using a forceful implement, the distance of the forced movement increases by 1 square.

Wondering if it applies to each...

The answer is quite niggly, in that it relies on the emphasized text in the quote above, namely:

> Mark of Storm's Slide isn't increased by the Forceful Property because you are not Pushing with an Attack Power, but with a Feat after you Hit wth an Attack Power.

This results in a `(1+1)+1=3` forced movement.